# half-carry/half-borrow flag in DAA instruction

Tags: math, flags, z80

Apologies for making this my second Z80 DAA question - I have pretty much implemented this instruction now, but there is one thing I'm not sure about - is the H flag set by this instruction at all? The Z80 manual says 'see instruction', but it only mentions the flag before DAA, not after it is executed.

I set the flags as follows:

S is set if result is negative (0x80 & result equals 0x80)
Z is set if result is zero
H (not sure hence this question)
P/V is set to the parity of the result (1 if even, 0 if odd)
N is left alone
C is set if the higher nibble of the original accumulator value is modified

Other than this, the instruction seems to perform as I expect it to :-) I hope someone can clear this up for me, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question. Yes, H flag's behaviour is not clearly documented because it is behaviour is non-standard with `DAA`.

If lower nibble (least significant four bits) of A is a non base-10 number (greater than 9 like A,B,C,D,E or F) **or** H flag is set, 6 is added to the register. This means even if lower nibble is in 0-9 range, you can force to add 6 to A register by setting H flag.

When it comes to your question, H flag **usually** remains untouched in my experience but you cannot depend on that because it is said that "the effect is non-standard" which means H flag may change or may not change depending on the situation. In cases like this, you should always think H flag is affected by the `DAA` instruction after execution even if you see it is not affected in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm clear on what the lower nibble calculation uses the H flag for, just wasn't sure what happened after this - I thought that since the C flag is set if the higher nibble is modified, H flag may be set if the lower nibble is modified - this would be in keeping with the behaviour of the other Z80 mathematical instructions, although the manual doesn't state this at all, so I will not assume it.

Answer (score 3):

I could only find [here](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Zilog/Z80/Z-80_Microcomputer_Handbook.PDF) that the half-carry/borrow flag is modified by DAA.

I recommend that this flag be set exactly as the AF (auxiliary carry) flag is set by the DAA and DAS instructions on x86 CPUs. I see no reason why there should be any difference in operation between i8080/i8085/Z80's and i8086's DAA/DAS.

The x86 DAA/DAS sets AF to 1 if it adjusts the lowest 4 bits of the accumulator by 6. If it does not adjust them, it resets AF to 0.

See the pseudo-code for DAA and DAS in the intel's (or AMD's) x86 CPU manuals.

Comment: As you know, there is no DAS instruction for Z80 CPUs. Z80's DAA instruction combines i8086's DAA and DAS instructions into one which means it differs from i8086's DAA at some point.

Comment: You've said "I see no reason why there should be any difference in operation between i8080/i8085/Z80's and i8086's DAA/DAS.". My comment was targeting that sentence. Examining x86's equivalent instructions wouldn't help much to explain H Flag's weird behaviour for Z80.

Comment: This would seem like logical behaviour, although it isn't mentioned in the Z80 manual - this bothers me a little :-(

Comment: @EmirAkaydın: that difference is assumed as understood.

Comment: @PhilPotter1987: neither Z80 nor x86 docs suggest that *after* DAA/DAS has executed, H/AF be used in some meaningful ways, they do not provide examples for such a use. And I don't think many people find H/AF useful after DAA/DAS. Perhaps none. If you want to be sure, see other docs for Z80 and compatible CPUs such as i8080 and i8085. Maybe they explain DAA better. Or... find someone with a Z80 computer (e.g. ZX Spectrum) and ask them to run a DAA test.